# Finding an index in a char array of a given column and row?

Tags: c++, algorithm

Here is my situation.

I have a word wrapping algorithm that generates text lines either when the width is too much, or it finds a \n or a '-' in the text.

It therefore does not include the '\n' into the text row itself. This is the challenging part for me.

I'm trying to make an algorithm that will return the index in the character array, given a row and a column.

So if the length of row 1 is 20 and the length of row 2 is 10, if row 1 originally had a '\n' it should account for this.

Ex:

the text is:

```
Hello blue sky\nworld
```

we then get 2 lines:

```
Hello blue sky
world
```

now if my caret is represented by '|' and I place it here:

```
  Hello blue sky
  |world
```

The result is not the 14th character, but rather the 15th character since the invisible '\n' must be accounted for.

The tricky part is if the word wrap decides to generate a '\n'

eg:

```
  Hello blue 
  sky
  |world
```

In this case the result should still be 15 since the wordwrap pushed a new row but not because a '\n'  was in the text.

Thanks

```
Here is my mess so far:

int AguiTextBox::indexFromColumnRow( int column, int row )
{
    int len = 0;
    int charCount = 0;
    std::string curChar;

    int curLen = 0;
    int bytesSkipped = 0;
    std::string::const_iterator it = getText().begin();
    std::string::const_iterator end = getText().end();

    if(textRows.size() == 0)
    {
        return -1;
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < row; ++i)
    {
        len = _unicodeFunctions.getUtf8StringLength(textRows[i]);

        for(int j = 0; j < len; ++j)
        {
            //skip characters that would not have passed the newline test
            do
            {
                curLen = _unicodeFunctions.bringToNextUnichar(it,end);
                curChar = getText().substr(bytesSkipped,curLen);
                bytesSkipped += curLen;
                charCount++;
            }
            while(curChar[0] < ' ');
        }

    }

    len = len = _unicodeFunctions.getUtf8StringLength(textRows[row]);


    if(column == 0 && charCount + 1 < getTextLength())
    {
        curChar = _unicodeFunctions.getUtf8SubStr(getText(),charCount,1);

        while(charCount < getTextLength() - 1)
        {
            if(curChar[0] < ' ' && curChar[0] != '\n')
            {
                charCount++;
                curLen = _unicodeFunctions.bringToNextUnichar(it,end);
                curChar = getText().substr(bytesSkipped,curLen);
                bytesSkipped += curLen;
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        if(curChar[0] == '\n')
        {
            charCount++;
            curLen = _unicodeFunctions.bringToNextUnichar(it,end);
            curChar = getText().substr(bytesSkipped,curLen);
            bytesSkipped += curLen;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < column; ++i)
    {
        do
        {
            curLen = _unicodeFunctions.bringToNextUnichar(it,end);
            curChar = getText().substr(bytesSkipped,curLen);
            bytesSkipped += curLen;
            charCount++;
        }
        while(curChar[0] < ' ');
    }

    return charCount - 1;
}

//and the opposite
AguiPoint AguiTextBox::columnRowFromIndex( int index )
{
    std::string::const_iterator it = getText().begin();
    std::string::const_iterator end = getText().end();

    std::string curChar;
    int charCount = 0;
    int len = 0;
    int byteCount = 0;
    int curLen = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < (int)textRows.size(); ++i)
    {
        len = _unicodeFunctions.getUtf8StringLength(textRows[i]);

        for(int j = 0; j < len; ++j)
        {

            //skip characters if needed
            curLen = _unicodeFunctions.bringToNextUnichar(it,end);
            curChar = getText().substr(byteCount,curLen);
            byteCount += curLen;

            while (curChar[0] < ' ' && curChar[0] != '\n')
            {
                curLen = _unicodeFunctions.bringToNextUnichar(it,end);
                curChar = getText().substr(byteCount,curLen);
                byteCount += curLen;
            }
            if(curChar[0] == '\n')
            {
                charCount++;
                if(charCount == index)
                {
                    return AguiPoint(j,i);
                }

            }
            charCount++;
            if(charCount == index)
            {
                return AguiPoint(j,i);
            }



        }
    }
    return AguiPoint(len,textRows.size() - 1);
}
```

Comment: *Show us your code*. What do you have so far and where is it going wrong?

Comment: @Jonathan Grynspan I posted my code, but it does not work very well.

Comment: Just so you know: assuming `getText()` returns a `std::string` by value, you should only call it once. Otherwise, the iterators aren't going to match up correctly (though I don't see you actually using them anywhere.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear to me exactly what you need to do with the data. Are you trying to write an editor or what exactly?

One thing you could do is build an array of pointers to the start of each line, and perhaps the length of each line as well.

This way, you can represent all the lines without modifying the underlying data.

But you should really better describe exactly the requirements of your converted data.

Comment: I'm making a TextBox that supports WordWrap and I need this functionality to delete at the caret position

Comment: This is not for Windows then, I'm guessing? Will my suggestion not work?